# Why is this PNG so gigantic?

Tags: graphics, load, size, png, jpeg

http://www.dtcontentguy.com/reviewold.png

Working on a page and somehow this PNG is roughly 50 MB.

We can always recut the image so fixing it isn't an issue. Instead I was wondering how could this file be 50 MB in the first place? It's only 752x70px. Image quality is also rather low.

Any ideas to this mystery?

Comment: "Image quality is also rather low" -- that would be JPEG you are thinking of. PNGs of 'low quality' may get compressed only slightly better, as PNG filters and compression work better with same or almost-the-same colors. In itself, PNG compression does not *cause* a worse quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image content ends at byte 97123, the rest is garbage.

It seems that something went wrong when saving the image (I don't want to consider the possibility that it's related to some exploit attempt...)

Here's the stripped image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdwgk.png

`cat reviewold.png  | head -c 97123 > reviewold_stripped.png`